# Use RxJava to make a periodic Retrofit request with ambWith and mergeWith?

Tags: retrofit, rx-java, retrofit2, rx-java2

I want to implement a repeating http request using RxJava in Android app with the following requirements:

1. The request should be made every 2 seconds.
2. The request should be made at most once per 2 seconds.
3. If a request times out at 2 seconds, we should cancel the request.

This is my RestService:

```
public interface RestService {    
    @GET("name")
    Single<String> getName();
}
```

I did some research online and this is what I implemented following this link: [Periodic HTTP Requests Using RxJava and Retrofit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31768184/periodic-http-requests-using-rxjava-and-retrofit)

```
Observable.interval(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.io())
        .map((tick) -> restService.getName())
        .subscribe(name -> Log.v("sampleApp", "received " + name));
```

I tested the code above and I think it satisfies requirement #1. But I am not sure how to tweak it to achieve requirement #2 and #3?

I saw a few examples using ambWith and mergeWith, but I don't understand them well. If someone could explain them or point to resources that explain them well, I will appreciate it!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe #2 is also satisfied by your example. As for timeout, just add *.timeout(long timeout, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit timeUnit)* right after *restService.getName()*, i.e. inside the *.map()* which is supposed to be *.flatMap()* by the way.